# .htaccess redirect HTTP[S]://domain1.com to HTTPS://WWW.domain2.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect `domain1.com` to `domain2.com` using `.htaccess`, as well as enforce www and https. I have seen partial answers to this question, but none that work for all 7 of these cases:

SOURCE URLS

1. `http://domain1.com`
2. `http://www.domain1.com`
3. `http://domain2.com`
4. `http://www.domain2.com`
5. `https://domain1.com`
6. `https://www.domain1.com`
7. `https://domain2.com`

TARGET URL:

```
https://www.domain2.com
```

This code only takes care of 1-4 above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`domain1.com`, `www.domain1.com`, and `domain2.com` are set up as aliases in the Apache virtual host file. I also tried using `RedirectMatch` in the host file, but I couldn't get that working.

Comment: I think his question is more appropiate for http://serverfault.com than for SO.

Comment: Does your SSL certificate include all 4 names: domain1.com, www.domain1.com, domain2.com and www.domain2.com ?

Comment: SSL certificate only has www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com.

Comment: @reporter It'll need a lot of work to be appropriate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would indeed be more efficient to do this in the virtual host. (`domain1.com` would ideally be set up as a seperate virtual host and have an unconditional `Redirect`.)

However, since you've tagged your question `.htaccess`, then try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> SSL certificate only has `www.domain1.com` and `www.domain2.com`

If your SSL cert doesn't include the apex domains `domain1.com` / `domain2.com` then you won't be able to redirect these (#5 and #7 in your list). (This is regardless of whether you do this in the main server config or `.htaccess`). The SSL handshake occurs first before any redirects can occur and the user will get an error in their browser before reaching your site.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it still isn't working correctly for cases 5-7. Maybe I should just add those apex domains to the cert and redirect from the virtual host.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to handle #6 (sorry, got the logic back to front on that one). But... yes, 5 & 7 won't work unless you have an SSL cert that covers the apex domains.